# why does the following code generate a "reference to 'tm' is ambiguous" error?

Tags: c++, namespaces, ambiguous, ambiguity

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace characters {
    char tm='a';
    char tc='a';
}

using namespace characters;

class table {
    public:
        void printline (){
            char m;
            m=tm;
            //m=tc;
            cout<<m<<m<<m<<m<<m<<m<<m<<m<<m;
        }
};

int main()
{
    table myTable;
    myTable.printline();

return 0;
}
```

but when you comment out the m=tm; line and reinstate the line m=tc the code works fine.

what is so special about the identifier tm?

Comment: `using namespace std;` is a bad practice and also is the cause of your bug. [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm)

Comment: [A good compiler will point you to the error](https://godbolt.org/z/vEcM9Ev1K).

Comment: Tested a theory: https://godbolt.org/z/W9n3W8E4K Not a `using namespace std;` issue. At least not this time. Next time... There will be a next time.

Comment: thanks guys i think i now know why using the identifier tm caused the ambiguity

Comment: @user4581301 its a `using namespace` issue ;) https://godbolt.org/z/aqWcoG5z4

Comment: @user4581301 thanks! it has now come to my attention that using the identifier tm in a namespace conflicts with the global struct tm.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Ah shoot. Should have looked at those diagnostics better. Well, at least it's a two-parter with the other `using`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using namespace characters;` is the issue, that brings `characters::tm` to the global namespace and makes the ambiguity with the global `struct tm`. The solution:

```
// using namespace characters;
using characters::tm;
```

That directs the compiler, if you meet `tm`, use here `tm` from the namespace `characters`.